# Why does mmap(2) with PROT_WRITE only require a readable fd?

Tags: posix, mmap

From the POSIX (IEEE Std 1003.1-2008) [section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) on `mmap`:

> The file descriptor fildes shall have been opened with read permission, regardless of the protection options specified.

Why is that? Seems like a descriptor opened `O_WRONLY` and mapped with `PROT_WRITE` and not `PROT_READ` shouldn't be problematic with respect to permissions, right?

Answer (score 0):

But the next line states that   :

`If PROT_WRITE is specified, the application shall ensure that it has opened the file descriptor fildes with write permission unless MAP_PRIVATE is specified in the flags parameter as described below.`

I think that the line that you have quoted means that **atleast**  the file descriptor to the file should be opened with read permission.It clearly says that the **applications should ensure** that proper level of permissions are granted first.

To try this I opened the file in READ ONLY mode and passed that descriptor to the mmap.

```
fd= open(file_name,O_RDONLY);  
mappedData = mmap(0,fdstat.st_size,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
```

But when I run the program error is thrown, namely:

> mmap: Permission denied

EDIT:
Sorry I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I understand why write permission is needed on the fd, but why is read permission needed?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not because of permissions, but because of virtual memory internals: allocation of actual RAM pages is triggered by page faults on first access to mmaped pages. These pages are filled with contents of mapped file. Filling them with zeros (in case of O_WRONLY opened file is mapped PROT_WRITE) would be a reasonable implementation, yet likely it has not many real world applications.

If for example just a few bytes in the page are changed, still the whole page will be owerwritten at `msync()` or `munmap()`. This would mean that if write-only file is maped and modified, efectivelly it will "trash" the real file, unless whole pages are correctly filled with data in momory.

As far as I know, page is not required to be 4KB or some other value, so using such mapping feature correctly would be tricky.

Comment: @kestaxs The question seems similar to my one...:-)  
Your explanation may work (although why to fill with zeros?) in the case of absent/new pages. But if MAP_FIXED is in use (my case) then why to fill/touch these pages at all?  
And your example of trashing is solved simply - if you want to modify(!) the file, just open it O_RDWR...

Comment: @leonp, after call to `mmap()` only some tables are arranged, but real memory is not allocated. It is allocated only when You do some I/O to this memory. So then this memory must be filled with some content (is seems POSIX allows only reading data from the mapped file, leaving random content would be insecure). Page fault (and allocation of real memory) happens when You write first byte to mapped page - You can't avoid touching the whole pages. At this moment some data must be written to allocated page.

Comment: @kestaxs I understand... But doesn't the MAP_FIXED solves this? I thought it should...

Comment: @leonp, no, MAP_FIXED only tells where (in process virtual memory) to place mapping of file, nothing else.

Comment: Can't the OS fill it with the actual contents (or garbage) but mark the area in memory as not readable?

Comment: @SheaLevy, to fill with actual contents You need read permission on fd (that is what fd opened O_WRONLY dosn't have). Leaving memory with previous values would be security risk (data leak from from other applications), so some data must be written when page is allocated (there are exceprions, for example MAP_UNINITIALIZED, but require custom kernel). I don't know if write-only VM pages are supported by any hardware (I'm not aware of specification to confirm such architecture exists).

Answer (score 0):

> why is read permission needed?

This is probably a problem related to processor's architecture.

Some architectures (e.g. Intel x86) may not be able to create write-only memory page for lack of hardware support.